# How do I get this freezing issue fixed on Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, 17.04, tty, bug-reporting

Both Ubuntu 16.04, and 17.04 have a freezing issue on my Yoga 2 11. It freezes, apparently at random, and forces me to reboot. The clock freezes up- even the seconds. No programs will run. Changing from TTY7 to TTY1/2/3/4/etc doesn't help- it's frozen. Major annoyance, especially if I'm using it to write, or gaming. I can post my logs as soon as it freezes, but I feel that this is a significant enough issue to be looked at.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and like I said, I'll post my logs to Ubuntu pastebin directly after a freeze.

update-- the output of cat /var/log/syslog (directly after a freeze/reboot)  has been posted

---

Update: Output of cat /var/log/syslog on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.2 LTS https://paste.ubuntu.com/25113438/
Output of sudo lshw
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25113449/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24457323/

Comment: Do you absolutely need `onboard`?  It adds the on screen keyboard BTW.

Comment: not necessarily... i could go without it

Comment: Nearly all of the errors in the log are overflows from `onboard`.  You could try removing it with `sudo apt remove onboard` and see if you get another freeze.

Comment: How much RAM? How much swap? Intel Bay Trail processors?

Comment: 3.7gb ram, swappiness at 10, yes

Comment: maybe it's my swappiness value? I just considered that

Comment: Didn't work. Neither did disabling onboard. here's my latest log https://paste.ubuntu.com/24464425/

Comment: In your comment "3.7gb ram, swappiness at 10, yes", if "yes" was the answer to Bay Trail processors, then we've found the problem. You didn't say how big your swap partition/file is.

Comment: Do you have Bay Trail processors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three **existing** problems... maybe more...

1. your file system has corruption (evidenced by the `fsck` messages in syslog)
2. `onboard` is failing (evidenced by the `onboard` messages in syslog)

**Update**:

3. You have Bay Trail processors, and there's a fix for the freezes. See [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803640/system-freezes-completely-with-intel-bay-trail)

---

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

---

Then I would completely **purge** (not just uninstall) all 3 components of onboard, and then reinstall it. Either use `Synaptic` ("complete removal") to do this, or use `sudo apt-get purge` or `sudo dpkg -P` commands in the `terminal`.

Comment: Didn't work. Neither did disabling onboard. here's my latest log https://paste.ubuntu.com/24464425/

Comment: What happened when you did the fsck? Did you purge and reinstall onboard? I don't see any more onboard error messages.

Comment: Oops, did every step but reinstall. I just reinstalled. I'll be back if I have a problem, or just to say thanks!

Comment: fsck didn't show any errors... that I could see. I can give you the output for that if need be

Comment: nope, that didn't work.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24469271/

Comment: The onboard errors have returned. If you don't use onboard, just purge it again. The fsck errors are still there, but I think they're against your /boot or /boot/efi partition /dev/sda2. Do you have Windows on this machine? If so, you can run a `chkdsk /f x:` where x is equivalent to sda2. See my other comment above about Bay Trail processors.

Comment: yes, I have windows... will purge onboard...

Comment: yes I have baytrail.... 

onboard purged, the fsck or whatever checks ran fine

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24473682/

Comment: I was playing Half Life 2: Lost Coast, if that's any help /shrug
https://paste.ubuntu.com/24473863/
I hope we can fix this bug because I'd rather not have to go back to using Windows all the time

Comment: I upvoted... seems to be working... for the moment at least. Thank you much

Comment: I actually looked into it closer and no, my Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit
vendor: Intel Corporation intel atom processor isn't considered bayrtrail or a baytrail derivative. I won't remove your answer, if I even can anymore, but if you could help me again it would be greatly appreciated, as I've hopped to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.2 and the freezing errors are still occuring

Comment: I unaccepted your answer just cuz I want one now.... Idk if Askubuntu doesn't really show questions with an answer or not, sorry for whatever rep I took away or whatever

Comment: Look at http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/55844/Bay-Trail?q=bay%20trail#@All and see if you find your exact processor there... they do show Z37xxx.

Comment: OH xxx is supposed to be numbers I took the x's literally okay thanks! I'll change the quiet splash thing

Comment: how would I edit this line in order to display text on boot?? Do you know off the top of your head? Do I just remove the quiet splash part and put "" instead??

Comment: @RobertSederholm after so long, I don't understand your question. Please explain.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer!! 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/766973/16-04-how-to-uninstall-plymouth
It's in the comments. Thanks!