# Ubuntu 19.04 systemd-analyze blame returns Bootup not finished

Tags: boot, systemd

I am using a Dell Laptop with Ubuntu Budgie 19.04.

Whenever I run the command :

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

it returns :

```
Bootup is not yet finished org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.FinishTimestampMonotonic=0).
Please try again later.
```

This, even if the computer booted hours ago and is working normally. Obviously, the boot process should have long terminated. Does this make sense to anyone? Is this the sign of any boot or load problem?

The command :

```
systemctl list-jobs
```

returns :

```
 JOB UNIT                                 TYPE  STATE  
  2 multi-user.target                    start waiting
142 systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service start waiting
 35 setvtrgb.service                     start waiting
155 plymouth-quit-wait.service           start running
151 getty@tty1.service                   start waiting
  1 graphical.target                     start waiting
149 getty.target                         start waiting
152 system-getty.slice                   start waiting
```

Answer (score 0):

For my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I was experiencing the same problem. Running a quick `systemctl` reveals that Plymouth (Ubuntu's silly little splash screen) was the one process that had a active status of ACTIVATING, which seems to block the boot process from finishing.

[Disabling plymouth](https://askubuntu.com/a/766991/657700) seems to fix the problem for me. Also, it allows to see which processes are running long wait jobs if you are trying to profile your start time.